# What exactly is a Softmax output layer?

Tags: deep-learning, softmax, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to make a simple conv net in c#, and I want to make a Softmax outputlayer, but I don't really now what it is. Is it a fully connected layer with Softmax activation or just a layer which outputs the softmax of the data?

Answer (score 1):

Softmax is just a function that takes a vector and outputs a vector of the same size having values within the range [0,1]. Also the values inside the vector follow the fundamental rule of probability ie. sum of values in vector  = 1.

```
softmax(x)_i = exp(x_i) / ( SUM_{j=1}^K exp(x_j) ) # for each i = 1,.., K
```

But sometimes people use Softmax classifier which refers to a MLP with input and 1 output layer (which makes it a linear classifier like linear SVM) where softmax function is applied to the outputs of output layer. This setup gives the probability of the input being close to each of the output classes.

Comment: just as a side note - softmax classifier as defined in the last part of the answer is **logistic regression**, it's connection to SVM is quite loose